# Object Initialization with an initializer block

Tags: scala

Yesterday I was reading a paper called: [How Scala Experience Improved Our Java Development](http://spot.colorado.edu/~reids/papers/how-scala-experience-improved-our-java-development-reid-2011.pdf).

Inside the Object Initialization section, it says:

> The idiomatic Scala technique for instantiating an object (which does
>   not expose all relevant parameters via constructor arguments) is to
>   create an anonymous subclass with an initializer block which calls
>   additional statements [Odersky et al.]:

I have been doing some tests:

```
class B {
  var x1: String = "B"

  def setText(text: String) {
    x1 = text   
  }

  override def toString = x1
}
```

I don't really understand why I can do:

```
scala> new B{setText("new Text")}
res23: B = new Text
```

but I can't do:

```
scala> new B{ setText "new Text" }
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
       new B{ setText "new Text" }
                      ^
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This hasn’t got much to do with the initialiser block. It’s just that the sugaring syntax

```
a b
```

means

```
a.b
```

and not

```
a(b)
```

Or in the general case

```
obj meth arg
```

is sugar for

```
obj.meth(arg)
```

with `arg` being optional.

If you want to specify this without the parentheses, you’ll have to write the receiving object before the method:

```
new B { this setText "new Text" }
```

If, for whatever reason, you want to save characters, you could add a self-type alias:

```
new B { o =>
  o setText "new Text"
  o setTitle "a Title"
  o setSomeOtherArgument someArg
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The "operator notation" requires an explicit receiver. For example:

```
print("hello");
```

Will work, but:

```
print "hello"
```

Won't.

Again this **will** work, and print `"hello"`

```
Predef print "hello"
```